# WPF C# - Programatically add Controls Caliburn.Micro

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I am new to MVVM and Caliburn.Micro and experimenting around with it.

Currently I am looking for a possibility to programmatically generate and add Controls, in this case Buttons, in a MVVM compatible way.

Is there a good way to dynamically add/generate controls and provide them functionality?

Comment: Where should the functionality come from? Is it hardcoded, e.g. some method in a ViewModel? If this is the case, why do you have to add the controls dynamically? Or do you mean adding more instances using the same template into a listbox?

Comment: Currently I am developing an App where the user has to login. According to his Userlevel (Admin, User, etc.), he is allowed to see specific content. My Idea was to add only the Controls he is allowed to use (in this case, buttons, to navigate to the Content). So the Button should switch the Content by calling the `ActivateItem` from the shell.

Comment: In this case, I would hide them if he is not allowed to use them (e.g. using a binding on the `Visibility` property). The View would be the same in both cases.

Comment: @LionAM will do it the way you suggested - thanks :)

Comment: I would make different view models (inheriting from the same base), and then pick the one to be used based on the user role. Each of teh view models should then have its own view.

Comment: in MVVM we use DataTemplates, which are selected by the Type contained within the DataContext or Content, depending on the control.

Comment: @Will do you have an example or a tutorial for me, which explains how I achieve that?

Comment: Tutorials are regularly indexed by search engines.  You'll be able to find the freshest by consulting one.  Lemme see if I can find an answer where I detail how to do this...  Here's one example which details how it works http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511285/setting-datatemplate-visualtree-in-datatemplate-triggers/11511661#11511661 Another example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27197955/c-sharp-public-observablecollectionviewmodel-instance-pass-items-to-protecte/27232644#27232644 Create a small prototype using those answers as guides and see if you understand how it works.